# Input value disables Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, password-protection

I have the most annoying problem ever! I'm using an easy to use password script:

```
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.myform.username.value;
    var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = ["Natalie"]; 
    var pwArray = ["0123456"]; 

    for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        window.location = "hello.html";
    } else {
        alert("ERRR! Wrong!");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now, I have done a FORM for this script:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()" name="myform">
    <input type="text" value="Natalie" name="username" style="width:0px;height:0px;border:0px solid;background:rgba(00,00,00,0);">
    <input type="text" name="pword" style="width:150px;border:1px solid #fff;font-family:roboto;font-size:12px;padding:1% 12%;text-align:center;letter-spacing:4px;font-weight:900;margin:2%;" value="Ex: 354627" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Ex: 354627')     {this.value=''}">
    <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Check In" onclick= " validate()">
</form>
```

Eveything works, except of typing in the password and **pressing the enter key!**

Why is that and how do I fix it? I took my time to put it all in a JSFiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/j9HFg/14/

Comment: what is the return false; for ? have you tried changing it to true or removing it altogether ?

Comment: You're actually using an easy to *break* password script. That should be done on the server-side!

Comment: Yes I know! But that's not the problem! It doesn't really matter right now if it's easy to break! I just got to get the enter key working!

Comment: This is why you shouldn't handle the submit button's `click` event - instead, handle the `submit` event for the `<form>`

Comment: if I change it to a submit event instead the script doesn't work... it will just redirect to mypage.com/?username=Natalie&pword=0123456&submit=Check+In

Comment: You probably want `<form method="POST" ...`

Comment: onSubmit="validate()" then? is method="POST" still needed?

Comment: I found problem: You have to use `input type='submit'`, instead of  `input type='button'`.

Comment: I changed it now, but now the script doesn't redirect to the page I've chosed!

Answer (score 2):

Your onclick event needs to have a `return` before `validate()`. You input type needs to be `submit` for your submit button. This will enable the enter key.

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Check In" onclick= "return validate()">
```

I might also instead make that an onsubmit event on the form

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()" name="myform">
```

The return is required because if we substitute the return value like so `onclick="false"`, the click event still propagates. But if we return false like so `onclick="return false"` then the event stops.

Also *very importantly*, usernames and password should **not** be in javascript. Please do that server-side.

Comment: It would useful to explain why return is required.

Comment: Okay, now the enter key works!!! =D I've added all the changes but now the problem now is that the url doesn't load. It only reloads the page!

Comment: Got it to work by adding `onchange="validate()"` to the text-input!

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work, because you are not clicking submit button.

I bet, that hitting enter key does not fire `onclick` event.

You have to add handler for `keyUp`, `keyPress` or something like this (im not JS expert).

---

Edit:

I just realized that you have `input type='button'` instead `input type='submit'`.

It should be like this:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Check In" onclick="validate()">
```

On that type of input onclick should work with enter key.

Comment: Ok so I would need to find a script then with submit rather than onclick!

Comment: onclick is triggered with enter key. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kysrN/)

Comment: @ogc-nick looks like it's triggered only on `input type='submit'`, but he has `input type='button'`